# python regular expression replace only in parentheses

Tags: python, regex

I would like to replace the `ー` to `－` in a regular expression like `\d+(ー)\d+(ー)\d+`. I tried `re.sub` but it will replace all the text including the numbers. Is it possible to replace the word in parentheses only?

e.g. 
`sub('\d+(ー)\d+(ー)\d+','4ー3ー1','-')` returns `'4-3-1'`. Assume that simple `replace` cannot be used because there are other `ー` that do not satisfy the regular expression. My current solution is to split the text and do replacement on the part which satisfy the regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a function for the `repl` argument in `re.sub` to only touch the match groups.

`import re
s = '1234ー2134ー5124'
re.sub("\d+(ー)\d+(ー)\d+", lambda x: x.group(0).replace('ー', '-'), s)`

Using a slightly different pattern, you might be able to take advantage of a lookahead expression which does not consume the part of string it matches to.  That is to say, a lookahead/lookbehind will match on a pattern with the condition that it also matches the component in the lookahead/lookbehind expression (rather than the entire pattern.)

`re.sub("ー(?=\d+)", "-", s)`

If you can live with a fixed-length expression for the part preceding the emdash you can combine the lookahead with a lookbehind to make the regex a little more conservative.

`re.sub("(?<=\d)ー(?=\d+)", "-", s)`

Answer (score 2):

You may use the Group Reference here.

```
import re
before = '4ー3ー1ーー4ー31'
after  = re.sub(r'(\d+)ー(\d+)ー(\d+)', r'\1-\2-\3', before)
print(after)  # '4-3-1ーー4ー31'
```

Here, `r'\1'` is the reference to the first group, a.k.a, the first parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

```
re.sub('\d+(ー)\d+(ー)\d+','4ー3ー1','-')
```

Like you pointed out, the output of the regular expression will be '-'. because you are trying to replace the entire pattern with a '-'. to replace the ー to － you can use

```
import re
input_string = '4ー3ー1'
re.sub('ー','-', input_string)
```

or you could do a find all on the digits and join the string with a '-'

```
'-'.join(re.findall('\d+', input_string))
```

both methods should give you '4-3-1'

Comment: OP already mentioned that this is not a good approach because it replaces —s when they aren't a part of the pattern as well. Please read above and fix your answer accordingly.

Comment: OP used replace on the entire string. one option is to use replace on the matching groups or replace the specific character only